# ogone error unknown order/0/s/

Tags: php, payment-gateway, sha

I'm trying to configure my script to use ogone payment gateway
i've assigned a pass phrase let's say e.g: abcd1234
so the code that will be hased is

```
$sh = "AMOUNT=5000abcd1234CURRENCY=USDabcd1234LANGUAGE=en_USabcd1234ORDERID=1122abcd1234PSPID=MyIDabcd1234";
```

and i'm using this form

```
<FORM METHOD="post" ACTION="https://secure.ogone.com/ncol/test/orderstandard.asp" id="form1" name="form1">
<INPUT type="hidden" NAME="PSPID" value="MyID">
<INPUT type="hidden" NAME="ORDERID" value="1122">
<INPUT type="hidden" NAME="AMOUNT" value="5000">
<INPUT type="hidden" NAME="CURRENCY" value="USD">
<INPUT type="hidden" NAME="LANGUAGE" value="en_US">
<INPUT type="hidden" NAME="SHASIGN" value="<?php echo $sh; ?>">
<input type="submit" value="Your button lib" id="submit2" name="submit2">
</form>
```

after adjusting the referrer URL of this webpage i get this error unknown order/0/s/
Any idea please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error ***unknown order/0/s*** means that you are not sending the proper SHA-1 signature.

This is related to a parameter configured in Ogone's backoffice there :

```
Configuration > Technical information > Data and origin verification
```

Comment: So the signature is wrong? What is the correct signature to enter? The plain text signature or the hashed value? Or yet something else?

Comment: here is the link 
https://epayments-support.ingenico.com/en/help/possible-errors/guide

Answer (score 0):

I am very late, but the answer to this question is to hash the SHASIGN value with an algorithm that is chosen within the Merchant portal.

Passing the hashed value solves the issue.